# 13A UK plug - wiring safety

Tags: electrical, uk, cord-and-plug

I have an older tumble drier with a BS1363 13A plug on it. The wires are starting to come out and be exposed.

Is this really unsafe? Should I attempt to fix this one or buy a new one? I tried undoing the terminals and pulling the slack up but there isn't enough room without cutting the cables.

Do the ends of the cables need to be capped or can they just be cut and stripped accordingly?

[image: before i touched it!]

[image: image of plug]

Comment: The old tumble dryer is a bigger risk to you than that plug - tumble driers are one of the most common causes of house fires, and older ones are responsible for most of those fires, as well as being so inefficient compared to modern ones that if you use it with any regularity a new one will pay for itself quite quickly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That would fail any safety inspection.

1. **Get a new plug.** Those side grip cable clamps do a very poor job [& that one was never even adjusted in the first place. That plug has been hazardous since it was first fitted.]. Get one with a standard 'strap' over the cable. Under £2 from any supermarket.
2. The individual wires must be cut shorter, so that the white outer sheath of the cable is held firmly by the clamp, not the individual wires, and there should be no 'spare wire' wrapped inside the plug - it probably wouldn't fit anyway when you try to get the top back on.

The trick is to offer up the cable sheath [white bit] so that it will nicely clamp, then using a thumbnail, mark the length of each individual wire, before cutting each. Most plugs require each to be a different length, earth longest, then neutral [blue] & live [brown] shortest.
This is, in itself, a safety measure, so if it does ever get pulled hard enough to rip the wires out, live disconnects first, then neutral, & earth last.

When finished it should look like this…

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
The 'strap' is reversible with one side capable of tightening in harder than the other, for different cable gauges. Remove it completely while you wire the plug, then choose which way round to put it back so it can clamp the cable properly.  A correctly clamped UK plug can withstand someone tripping over it without sustaining damage to either plug, socket or wiring. They are highly over-engineered to be tough.
There is no need to do anything more than twist the wire ends where they are exposed. Make sure each exposed end is exactly the right length to go completely through the hole on each pin, with no spare visible either front or back.

If you fit the brown first, then blue, then green, you'll find it easier. You can push each pin upwards if you find that helps to get the wire in each hole. Fit the grip last.

Comment: …and thank you everybody, for letting me see deleted posts on here;))) 10k reached, at last. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArPnB.png [this message will self destruct in the morning]

Comment: Also to note that new plugs come with different fuse ratings. For a tumble dryer it is highly likely you'll want a 13A fuse.  Those are brown, as in these pictures. If the one you buy has a different fuse (3A=red is common), transfer the fuse from your old plug.

Comment: The design for this is actually quite smart. The length of the wires itself is a safety feature. If you yank on the wire so hard that you disconnect the wires, the live one will come out first, then neutral, and then finally ground.

Comment: Some plugs have a bit of card over the pins telling you how long to cut the wires (and how long to strip), which is an alternative to marking them off against the plug - easier if you have a ruler to hand, harder if you don't.  And note that there's a little room for excess bare cable on the neutral and earth at least in the picture.  Better an extra mm than too short to grip properly.

Comment: Good practice at our location is it make the ground wire a bit longer, so it disconnects last, should one rip out the cord. I don't know if the design of the UK plugs already provides this safety eature

Comment: @Martin if you follow the dimensions and do it properly, yes.  If you cut all the cores to the same length and somehow manage to cram them in, no.  And you'll probably crush them putting the plug back together.  So in theory but it's not foolproof

Comment: @Martin - it should do that anyway if it's been done properly. They're designed like that. I tried to do a video demo, but I just don't have enough hands.

Comment: I bought a new 13a plug from B&Q & fitted it recently. It wasn't too difficult at all but I did need to cut & strip all three wires slightly. The cable is now held properly and it feels far more secure. It's been fine since. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's parallax, but the brown wire does look like it's sliding out a bit. And the brown wire is the wire that would slide out if the whole cable were pulled out of the plug.

That the brown wire can slide indicates a loose connection and risk of fire there, especially at the currents dryers may pull.

Two things are necessary for this plug to be repaired and put back into service:

1. The screw holding the brown wire in should be tightened so the brown wire is properly held in and cannot move (a torque screwdriver might be needed to get the correct torque on the screw).
2. The "grabber" in the plug body that clamps down on the white/tan cable sheath over the three wires must be in place so the whole cable is held firmly by the plug body when the plug is reassembled and the cable can't pull out of the plug.

If either of these are not possible with the existing plug, a new identical plug needs to be put on the cable properly. See [Tetsujin's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/285703/140350) for the proper way to install a European/UK plug, which I'm not familiar with (I'm more used to USA plugs and instructions that come with them).

Comment: Thanks. If I did need to restrip the cables do I need to crimp some sort of end on them? Looks like there is no cord clamp either so I'll have to buy a new plug.

Comment: That looks like European wiring colors. Across the pond I have not put crimps on stranded wires when replacing plugs: just get all the strands twisted up, stuff the twist in the hole, and screw down tight. The instructions for the new plug may say what to do. A special tool would be necessary if crimps are needed. And without a cord clamp, I agree it's time for a new plug.

Comment: Downvoter please explain?

Comment: Your answer is missing some vital details, for a user with no prior experience. Suggesting the cable can be transferred to another plug without further modification is just wrong.

Comment: Added indication to follow instructions on th e new plug for safety.

Comment: There are no instructions with a plug. It's just a plug, rarely even packed, they're just loose with a barcode stuck on top for the till. People buying them are expected to know how to do it… which may in itself be a failing, but that's how it is.

Comment: OK, maybe a UK/European thing. The plugs I buy in US have instructions how to install them. Strange the Euro lawyers haven't got hold of that, lots of room for lawsuits.

Comment: Everything here must have a plug fitted for sale, so most consumers never need to deal with them at all. Failure to properly research is not grounds for a lawsuit over here. OP was wise to ask.

Comment: Here in the UK plugs come with an instruction card that has a diagram of where the wires should go and tells you the wire lengths and colour codes etc, but it doesn't give detailed instructions.

Comment: I think the excess bare wire on the live (brown) is just poor assembly in the first place.  There's a hint visible in the earth  (green/yellow) too, and possible even the neutral (blue) from the way it bends.

Answer (score 2):

The little bits of metal crimped onto the ends of the wire are "ferrules".  They are often used when putting fine stranded wire into a terminal that's not really meant to take stranded wire.  Ferrules can be bought, and you'll need a crimp tool to fit them.

But the standard UK plugs have been used with stranded wires for years.  Make sure the ends of the wires are neatly twisted together before pushing them into the terminals, and all will be well.

Comment: Ferrules are used in manufacturing because they make it easier to guarantee good assembly quickly.  With the *proper* crimp tool they're good.  I wouldn't want to use them here with any non-proper way of crimping. All plugs sold in shops are designed for stripped stranded  wire anyway.

Comment: You don't have to cut the ferrules off the wires, almost certainly you can slide the sheath of the cable back over the wires by grabbing the cable where it enters the appliance, pulling it while letting it slide through your grip till you reach the plug end, and repeat this a few times if needed. Surprisingly little force is required. Then, if the strain relief of the existing plug doesn't reliably grab the sheath, you should replace the plug. Ferrules are very desirable for a high power appliance.

Comment: @Jussi there should be strain relief on the appliance end too, and that might not be easy to loosen.  And on a long cable there is a lot of friction between inner and outer insulation.  And then what if the difference in required lengths changes significantly?

Answer (score 2):

@Tetsujin's pic is helpful ... but the earht (yellow/green) should actuually have been a bit longer - you can see to the left there is space to loop the cable a bit longer.  The earth should always be longest so that if wires ever did pull out it is the last to detach - so keeps the circuits protected - that is why the plug design gives more generous space for the earth cable. The different cable paths are meant to ensure live would be first to detach, then neutral and finally earth if somehow the cable got ripped from the plug.  Same "earth longest" is true for the pins - it ensure when pluggging in connection is earthed first - and when pulling plug out earth leaves last.